# Union of two object bags in Java

Tags: java, object, interface, union, bag

I need help with a Java homework problem. I have two bags, say `bag1` containing the strings `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and `bag2` containing strings `E`, `F`, `G` and `H`. I need to write a BagInterface for the union of those two bag then a class call `ArrayBag<T> implements BagInterface<T>`.

BagInterface I was thinking something like this:

```
public interface BagInterface<T> {

    public T union(T[] item);
}

public class ArrayBag<T> implements BagInterface<T> {

    private final static int DEFAULT_CAP = 4;
    private int numElements;
    private T[] bag;

    public ArrayBagR(int cap) {
        bag = (T[]) new Object[cap];
        this.numElements = 0;
    }

    public T union(T[] item) {

        // Not sure how I should write this so I can pass
        // another class object in the parameter

        // Like say if I write a main to run this I could
        // do something like Bag1.union(Bag2)
        // and get something like A B C D E F G H
    }
}
```

Like say if I have this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BagInterface bag1 = new ArrayBag(n);
    BagInterface bag2 = new ArrayBag(m);
    BagInterface<String> everything = bag1.union(bag2);
}
```

Comment: what does `union` do? does it create a new `BagInterface` instance? does it perform union of the parameter with the current bag?

Comment: Yes it should create a new BagInterface instance and add the two current bag's string into the new bag.

Answer (score 3):

Per your example,

```
BagInterface bag1 = new ArrayBag(n);
BagInterface bag2 = new ArrayBag(m);
BagInterface<T> everything =  bag1.union(bag2);
```

When you call, `union` on `bag1` passing `bag2` as argument,

```
 this.bag -> represents bag1
 item in the argument represent bag2
```

Now you can write something line. No need to return from this method. **`bag1` will be updated with union.**

```
 public BagInterface<T> union(T[] item) {
    T[] everything = thi.bag;
    for(T elem: item){
       if(not(this.bag contains elem )){
          everything  -> add(elem);
       }
    }
    return this;
 }
```

Please note: This is a pseudo code to share the concept (not a code).

A sample java code can be like below:

```
 public BagInterface<T>  union(T[] item) {
        List<T> unionList = Arrays.asList(this.bag);
        for(T elem: item){
           boolean present = false;
           for(T elem1: this.bag){
              if(elem1.equals(elem)){
                  present = true;
              }
           }
           if(!present){
               unionList.add(elem);
           }
        }
       this.bag = unionList.toArray(new Bag[unionList.size()]);
       return this;
     }
```

Also you can further use `List` method `contains` to simplify the code as :

```
       public BagInterface<T> union(T[] item) {
        List<T> unionList = Arrays.asList(this.bag);
        for(T elem: item){
           if(!unionList.contains(elem)){
               unionList.add(elem);
           }
        }
        this.bag = unionList.toArray(new Bag[unionList.size()]);
        return this;
     }
```

If you don't want to update `bag1` contents, you should have method like this:

```
       public BagInterface<T> union(T[] item2) {
                BigInterface<T> everything = new BagArray<T>();
        List<T> unionList = Arrays.asList(this.bag);
        for(T elem: item){
           if(!unionList.contains(elem)){
               unionList.add(elem);
           }
        }
        everything.setBags(unionList.toArray(new Bag[unionList.size()]));
        return everything;
     }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am really trying to understand this but I just can't. I'm trying to get it to the step that the book shown as having BagInterface<String> everything = bag1.union(bag2); which executes the bag "everything" to contain the Strings from both bags.

Comment: I update the answer with methods to return the value. Please let me know, if still doesn't help.